# Querying key-value map in mongo

Tags: mongodb

I have documents stored in mongo database following this schema:

```
{
   map:{
         key1:value,
         banana:value2 
         ....
        }

}
```

How can I query objects based on keys in this map ?

e.g I want to get all the documents which map contains key that equals `banana`.

Answer (score 21):

Maps are accessed the same way as normal nested values.
This means that you can use the `$exists` operator to check if the key exists.

```
db.collection.find( { "map.banana" : { $exists : true } } );
```

Comment: Could you please [edit] in an explanation of why this code answers the question? Code-only answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148272/274165), because they don't teach the solution.